# Basic PyCharm questions

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a seemingly simple task to do.  Run this ( print('Hello World') ) line of code in PyCharm.  No, I'm serious.  I wont bother complaining about what I've tried or how much I've coded in the past (spoiler alert, a lot) because I just want to get it running.  The online tutorial wants me to do some kind of project structure thing before I can even start, which didn't even work to begin with.  I really just want to be able to run code from a file, so if anyone who's figured it out can tell me in a

"
Do this

then this

finally this
"

type format that would be wonderful, because I cant even run a single line from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's really simple, if you used any code editor in the past you probably will understand what i'm doing here:

File >> New >> Python File >> "name of the file" >> Create.

To run the code simply click the play icon which is run 'project'.
Then the output should appear in a console.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

Create folder wherever you want your file to be

Open this folder in pycharm as your project (if you have a project open, close it and open this folder as your new project)

Open `Project` tab on the left

Right click your folder -> New -> Python File -> Create `hello.py` with `print 'Hello World'` as contents

From the top menus, go to `Run`-> from the drop-down click `Run`

Click `hello` so it knows to run that.

If you don't want to deal with the `Run` stuff you can always invoke your script from the command line with `python hello.py`.

Hello World! should appear in your console!